# Setting QList sub object

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Helo there,

I'm setting one object to get it in QML... in this object definition I get

```
(location_in_my_computer):25: candidate constructor 
not viable: no known conversion from 'QList<QString>' to 'QList<const QString> &' 
for 10th argument GroupObject(...,
    ^
```

In my code I use this classes (minimal examples):

```
class GroupObject : public QObject
{ 

public:
    GroupObject(QObject *parent=0);
    GroupObject( 
                QList<const QString> &tags, QObject *parent=0);

    QList<const QString> tags(); 

    void setTags(QList<const QString> &tags); 

private: 
    QList<QString> m_tags; 
};
```

And his implementation:

```
#include "groupobject.h"

GroupObject::GroupObject( QList<const QString> &tags, QObject *parent) QObject(parent),
    m_tags(tags){

    }

QList<const QString> GroupObject::tags()
{
    return m_tags;
}

void GroupObject::setTags(QList<const QString> &tags)
{
    if(tags != m_tags){
        m_tags = tags;
    }
}
```

And I call to set one QList of GroupObject in follow example:

```
QList<QString> tags;
QList<QObject*> dataList;
dataList.append( new GroupObject( tags ));
```

How I can do this in right concept?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `tags` is `QList<QString>`, however `GroupObject` contrustuctor accepts `QList<const QString>`.

Actually the `const` modifier for `QString` does not make any sense in `QList`, since it does not protect from `QList` modification. It just denies modification of `QList` items. In that case you cannot even copy one such `QList` item during `QList` initialization.

So, to compile your code you have to change `QList<const QString>` by `QList<QString>`. In some places you may also want to protect from modification actual `QList` object, for example:

```
// do not allow GroupObject(...) to change external 'tags' instance
GroupObject(const QList<QString> &tags, QObject *parent=0);

// return reference to internal object field and
// do not allow callers to use that reference for changing that internal field
// it does not change instance of GroupObject, so
// there is 'const' modifier of the member function.
const QList<QString>& tags() const;

// or provide full copy of returned object
QList<QString> tags() const;

// do not allow to change external 'tags' inside 'setTags()'
void setTags(const QList<QString> &tags);
```

By the way, there is the `QStringList` class in Qt for lists of `QString` that provides additional functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to pass it by value, then `QList<QObject*> dataList` is unnecessary. A `QObject` is also an owning container for objects. Thus you could also write:

```
class F {
  QObject data;
  ...
  void foo() {
    QStringList tags = ...;
    new GroupObject(tags, &data);
    ...
  }
  void bar() {
    // iterate all data objects
    for (auto obj : data.children()) {
      auto group = qobject_cast<GroupObject>(obj);
      if (group) { qDebug() << group.tags(); continue; }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

By leveraging a `QObject` as an owning container for other objects, you don't have to worry about resource leaks. It will delete all the children that it owns. Since you hold `data` by value, you don't even need to write a destructor. Leverage the compiler to manage the resources for you, it's good at it :)